# How to go to same Fragment from different Fragments using Navigation in android?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, navigation

I have 3 different fragments in the same activity, and the Activity contains a toolbar with a settings button. When I press the settings button, the Settings Fragment should open. How can I implement this using Navigation? Should I create an action from every single fragment to Settings fragment or there is a simple way? (considering that the settings button is in activity layout).
I also created a diagram for better understanding. If you have any questions let me know. Thanks

**This is how I set the navigation graph in my activity:**

```
private fun setDefaultNavGraph(bundle: Bundle?){
    fragmentContainer = my_nav_host_fragment as NavHostFragment
    val inflater = fragmentContainer.findNavController().navInflater
    val graph = inflater.inflate(R.navigation.prb_navigation)
    fragmentContainer.findNavController().setGraph(graph, bundle)
}
```

**And this is my activity xml file:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.eschbachit.citylinemobile.activities.PrbModuleActivity">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/toolbar_height"
        android:background="@color/toolbarDarkGrey"
        app:theme="@style/ToolbarColoredWhiteIcon"
        app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
        app:contentInsetEnd="0dp">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:id="@+id/back_btn"
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingTop="16dp"
            android:paddingBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/back_button_icon"
            android:tint="@color/white"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:contentDescription="@null"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/prb_activity_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:text="@string/title_activity_main"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_default"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="4sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/settings_nav_tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_settings"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_default"
        android:paddingTop="12dp"
        android:paddingBottom="12dp"
        android:gravity="center" />

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/my_nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Expecting all your fragments lie on a single activity, you can do it in following ways :-

1. Adding action (as you said)

`Navigation.findNavController(...).navigate(destination.id);`

2. You can also popBackStack if the parent of Fragment A,B,C is Settings Fragment.

   Navigation.findNavController(...).popBackStack();

Comment: And I have to implement  Navigation.findNavController(...).navigate(destination.id); in all fragments?

Comment: Can you give me an example of code for this? Please.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION:**

The thing I was looking for was a Generic action in my nav_graph.
I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63925818/15352563).

**I added this action to my navigation file and I used it in my activity in setOnClickListener method.**

```
<action android:id="@+id/openOnlineSettingsFragment"
    app:destination="@id/onlineSettingsFragment"
    app:enterAnim="@anim/pull_in_right"
    app:exitAnim="@anim/push_out_left"
    app:popEnterAnim="@anim/pull_in_left"
    app:popExitAnim="@anim/push_out_right" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Create two graph one `main_graph` and another `fragments_graph`. Add `settingFragment` to `main_graph` and also include `fragments_graph` to `main_graph` as follow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_graph"
    app:startDestination="@+id/settingFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/settingFragment"
... />
    <action
        android:id="@+id/goToSetting"
        app:destination="@id/settingFragment" />

    <include app:graph="@navigation/fragments_graph" />

</navigation>
```

Now write a method that its action is the following and this will do what you want: (put it in parent activity)

```
findNavController().navigate(MainGraphDirection.goToSetting())
```